# export firebase data node to pdf report

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

What a have is a mobile app emergency message system which uses Firebase as a backend.  When the end of an emergency event ends, I would like to capture the message log in a pdf document.  I have not been able to find any report editors that work with Firebase.  This means I may have to export this to php mysql.  The Firebase php SDK looks to be to much overkill for this task.  I have been googling php get from firebase and most responses have to do with using the Firebase php SDK.  Is this the only way it can be acomplished?

Comment: To which product do you relate? (https://firebase.google.com/products/)

Comment: I am using the Realtime Database presently

Comment: Have you considered using Cloud Functions?

Comment: removed the `php` tag and added an explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [PDF Kit](http://pdfkit.org) ([...](http://pdfkit.org/docs/guide.pdf)) on [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/) (it's all nodeJS, no PHP available there).

On npmjs.com there are several packages for [@firebase-ops](https://www.npmjs.com/~firebase-ops), [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) and [@google-cloud](https://www.npmjs.com/org/google-cloud).

In order to read from Firebase and write to [Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#storage-upload-object-nodejs) or [Data Store](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-datastore-ga); that example script would still require a database reference and a storage destination, to render the PDF content (eventually from a template) and puts it, where it belongs. also see [firebase / functions-samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts) (especially the `package.json` which defines the dependencies). `npm install -g firebase-tools` installs the tools required for deployment; also the requires need to be [installed](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/how-to-update-an-out-of-date-package-json/) in order to be locally known (quite alike composer - while remotely these are made known while the deployment process).

You'd need a) Firebase [Event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) [onUpdate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder#onUpdate)() as the trigger, b) check the `endTime` of the returned [DeltaSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) for a value and c) then render & store the PDF document. the code may vary, just to provide a coarse idea of how it works, within the given environment:

```
'use strict';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const bucket = gcs.bucket( 'some-bucket' );
const fs = require('fs');

// TODO: obtain a handle to the delta snapshot

// TODO: render the report
var pdf = new PDFDocument({
    size: 'A4', 
    info: {Title: 'Tile of File', Author: 'Author'}
});
pdf.text('Emergency Incident Report');

pdf.pipe(
    // TODO: figure out how / where to store the file
    fs.createWriteStream( './path/to/file.pdf' )
).on('finish', function () {
    console.log('PDF closed');
});

pdf.end();
```

externally running PHP code is in this case nevertheless not run on the server-side. the problem with it is, that an external server won't deliver any realtime trigger and therefore the file will not appear instantly, upon time-stamp update (as one would expect it from a Realtime Database). one could also add [external web-hooks](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http) (or interface them with PHP), eg. to obtain these PDF files through HTTPS (or even generated upon HTTPS request, for externally triggered generation). for local testing one can use command `firebase serve`, saves much time vs. `firebase deploy`.

the point is, that one can teach Cloud Function how the PDF files shall look alike, when they shall be created and where to put them, as micro-service which does nothing else but to render these files. scripting one script should be still within acceptable range, given all the clues provided.